# Laravel 5.2: How to add a register page?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2,
and I use `php artisan make:auth` to make register page and login page.

Now, I would want to make two separated register pages,which used by two roles,seller and  buyer ,
the two register pages named `seller-register.blade.php` and `buyer-register.blade.php`,
in view,add a item named `userType`,respectively corresponding  seller and buyer,like this:

**seller-register.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/seller-register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">User Type</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="c-input c-radio">
                                    <input id="userType" name="userType" type="radio" value="1" checked>
                                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                                    seller
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**
How to  modify controller and other something?